# How to use time selector in web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, time

I have a Time Picker control

```
<cc1:TimeSelector ID="TimeSelector1" runat="server" DisplaySeconds="false" 
SelectedTimeFormat="TwentyFour" />
```

And I am storing value like below mentioned format

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2} {3}", TimeSelector1.Hour, TimeSelector1.Minute, TimeSelector1.Second, TimeSelector1.AmPm));
```

But I select time from time selector in 24 hours format but the stored value shows in 12 hour format.I mean(`I selected 22:00 from time selector but the time shows the selected value as  10:00 pm`) What changes should I made in my data retrieving code??

Comment: is this a usercontrol that you created? if not please post the link for the corresponding control.

Comment: @Frebin Francis, its a third part user control .see this    (http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/TimePicker-control-in-ASPNetwith-example.aspx )

Comment: What do you mean with retrieved value shows in 12 hour format? It is stored in DateTime variable time and not a string. 22:00 == 10:00PM

Comment: @Sara John what do you want to do with this selected time ?

Comment: @ Frebin Francis, I want to store it in database in selected 24 hour format

Comment: which datatype are you using for storing this value? and which is your database server ?

Comment: @ Frebin Francis, presentl i am not saving this value in database. Now I just save in a variable which I mentioned above